Cisco Catalyst 1000 WebGUI Radius login
I'm trying to connect a newly acquired Catalyst 1000 to the centralized management of the company. We use Radius to the authentication for the network device management. It works as intended for all the other devices (Catalyst 2960+, and Aruba switches), but I fail to set it up properly on the Catalyst 1000.
I'm able to authenticate into this switch with my Radius credentials from both SSH and local console (so the connection to the Radius server cannot be the problem), but it doesn't work for the webGUI. Anytime I enter my credentials into the webGUI, it just acts like I gave wrong ones. According to the Radius logs, the server gets the authentication request from the switch, and gives a positive response, yet the switch refuses to log me in. Once again, only for the webGUI, both through local console and SSH it authenticates me as it supposed to. Also, I can log into the webGUI with the local credentials if I switch the ip http authentication from AAA to local. The only combination that doesn't work is using Radius for the webGUI.
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default group radius local
aaa authentication login CON local
aaa authentication enable default group radius enable
aaa authentication ppp default none
aaa authentication ppp DIAL local
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group radius
!
!
!
no ip http server
ip http banner
ip http authentication aaa
ip http secure-server
!

The webGUI is not exactly crucial to our normal use-case, but it drives me crazy I cannot make it work, when it works on all the other devices.
I would be greatful for any ideas about it. Thank you.

From a basic security perspective, the first thing you do is disable the HTTP and HTTP secure server.

Ensure that the RADIUS server configuration is correct and that the Catalyst 1000 is properly configured to communicate with the RADIUS server.
Ensure that the IP address, shared secret, and authentication methods are correctly configured on   the RADIUS server
Configure HTTP Authentication Correctly
aaa new-model
!
aaa authentication login default group radius local
aaa authentication enable default group radius enable
aaa authentication login webgui group radius local
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group radius
!
ip http server
ip http secure-server
ip http authentication aaa


Thank you for the answer. It didn't help anything though. As I said, the Radius server is set up correctly. 15 other switches work perfectly with it. Also, this switch works too when it comes to SSH or local console connection. It's only the webGUI and only on this switch that doesn't work. I tried the suggested configuration change (adding aaa authentication login webgui group radius local to the config) but the behavior stayed the same.

I have noticed one more thing. In your configuration you have disabled http server
with the below command ( no ip http server).
!
no ip http server
ip http banner
ip http authentication aaa
ip http secure-server
!

Yes, I disabled the http server. The WebGUI is already considered a security vulnerability, I won't enable non-https login to it.
